# File Upload to Solr is stuck

Tags: solr

I am trying to upload a file given in example folder of Solr for indexing but the processing is not completing.
 What can be the reason & how can I upload a file & get it indexed via Solr.
[image: status of command to upload the file.]

Comment: Do you see anything happening in the Solr log? Does the Admin panel show anything for the `films` collection at all?

Comment: I don't know where to check Solr logs & nothing changes on Admin panel. And on command prompt it is stuck like shown above. I tried using Postman also but there also request is not completing.

Comment: The Solr log will be displayed in the console if you start Solr with the `-f` argument to `bin/solr`, or you can go to `Logging` in the Admin interface, or check out the logs directory under the solr installation directory. What happens if you open the URL directly in your browser (i.e. you're not submitting anything, but accessing the URL at least).

Comment: Strange, now it worked. Though earlier I didn't add _text_ field in schema. Now I added it twice by mistake via Post request in Postman to http://localhost:8983/solr/films/schema/ with the body - {"add-copy-field" : {"source":"*","dest":"_text_"}}

Comment: So do I need to add this field twice or once, as I am not able to delete that field.